# Adding a dodge roll. Unity

Tags: unity, c#, scripting

I'm a newbie here. I need to add a second collider in CharacterController in the separate script with possibility to enabling/disabling them. I tried to find answer how to do it but I find nothing. Thanks for any help!

Comment: So, what did you try so far? What was the behaviour you observed, and how did that differ from the behaviour you want?

Comment: What exactly is a "dodge roll" in the context of your particular game? Is it a state where the character collides with some objects (like walls) but not with others (like enemy projectiles)?

Comment: Well, I need to implement dodge roll for my character to be able to go under objects. Now my player’s capsule collider collides with an obstacle and doesn’t allow player to pass under it. I need to add a new collider in CharacterController and make a change from one collider to another during this roll.

Comment: Changing or modifying a player's collider brings in a LOT of complications. You should have 2 colliders, one is on a layer that only colliders with the objects you can "roll under". And you can toggle this collider, while maintaining the main collider, which never collides with things you can "roll under". But hot swapping colliders entirely will lead to tons and tons of bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the collider of your character during the "doge roll" state.

The [`CharacterController`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-CharacterController.html) has the properties [`.center`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController-center.html) and [`.height`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController-height.html) which affect the physical shape of the character's capsule collider. You could temporarily reduce them during the "dodge roll" state to make the character shorter and reset these back to the original values when leaving that state.

But remember to keep in mind what happens when the dodge roll ends while the character is under an object. If you increase the capsule collider at that time, you might run into some really weird physics interactions. In the best case, you might see some stuff fly around in funny trajectories. In the worst case, your player gets stuck. So make up your mind about what to do in that situation. One possible solution could be to add crouching to your game. Transfer the character to the "crouching" state so they can crouch out from under the object.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't even know that if you change the collider in CharacterController the scale of the model will not change.

Comment: Mutating colliders is very bug prone and performance heavy on the physics system. I provided an alternative answer that involves toggling between colliders, and proposed a setup I've used in real life scenarios. Whichever solution you choose, I wish you luck. It's a complex problem with lots of edge cases.

Answer (score 2):

It is HIGHLY inadvisable to mutate a collider during runtime. This will lead to many many bugs and weird physics artifacts. Not to mention it puts strain on the physics system, as a lot of the broad phase and narrow phase cullings can rely on the shape of the collider being cached. Changing the shape will require the physics system to re evaluate these entries. My recommendation is to have two colliders that you toggle between. Simple disable your standing collider, and enable your rolling collider. However we can go further to increase the safety of what you're trying to do. Imagine the following setup:

```
PlayerGameObject
  {} PlayerController.cs
   - CollidersGameObject
     - StandingBodyColliderGameObject - Layer: "Default"
       {} Collider
     - RollingBodyColliderGameObject - Layer: "Default"
       {} Collider (Rolling) // Disabled
   - RollUnderColliderGameObject - Layer: "Roll Under"
     {} Collider (Same as standing but only collides with Roll Under)
```

The idea here is you have your standing and rolling hitboxes for physical interactions with other things in the game. However in your collision matrix, make it so the "Roll Under" layer only collides with itself. This means your normal collider will pass through and surfaces you could roll under. However if you have your RollUnderCollider enabled, it will collide with those surfaces and stop the player from being able to move through. When you roll, simply disable this collider. This will let your character phase through. If you want your player's standard hitbox to also shrink, disable the standing body collider and enable rolling body collider. However this rolling body collider will still phase through the roll under. This means that if your surface is slightly slanted, or not the exact right height, your roll will still work. When your roll is over, check if there's a roll under object above you (you can use physics queries for this). If not, restore your RollUnderCollider. Again, the reason for this multi collider setup is physics performance, edge case safety, and less constraint on level design. What you're trying to do isn't an easy problem, and an easy solution will likely turn complex very quickly as you go through edge cases. This is just my recommendation from time in the industry and dealing with changing colliders.